# How to run entire file and see the output in RStudio console?

Tags: r, rstudio

OK, so if I select the entire file and click "Run" then the program runs and I see the output in the console. Is there a shortcut for doing this?

If I click "Source" then I just see this in the console:

```
> source('~/Documents/myPrg.R')
```

Comment: > source('~/Documents/myPrg.R', echo = TRUE)

Comment: @gdkrmr's answer is the "Source with echo" menu choice (on the drop down associated with "Source").

Comment: of course, I ignored the tag being `rstudio` and not `r` :-)

Comment: "Source with Echo" works now. Perhaps I didn't have the working directory set correctly.